# Showing decimal places (Python 2.7 and Decimal datatype)

Tags: python-2.7, decimal

I am trying to code a currency converter program, and instead of using floats am trying to code the program in Python 2.7.5 using the decimal data type.

The program works and displays a result, but when using the getcontext().prec = 2 this is limiting the amount of numbers shown to 2, not the number of decimal places

code shown below:

```
#setup the decimal data type (including number of decimal places)
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 2

#get the current value and type from the user
currencyAmount = decimal.Decimal(raw_input('please enter the amount: '))
currencyType = int(raw_input('please enter the type (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 =      yen): '))

#set the exchange rates (based on sterling)
euro = decimal.Decimal('1.5')
dollar = decimal.Decimal('2.7')
yen = decimal.Decimal('30.8')

#convert the currency into pound sterling
if (currencyType == 2):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / euro
elif (currencyType == 3):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / dollar
elif (currencyType == 4):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / yen

#ask the user what currency they want it converted into
currencyConvert = int(raw_input('please enter the currency you would like to convert to (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 = yen): '))

#convert the currency into the new format (pound already done in previous steps)
if (currencyConvert == 2):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * euro
elif (currencyConvert == 3):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * dollar
elif (currencyConvert == 4):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * yen

#display the result to the user
print 'the result of the currency conversion was ',  currencyAmount
```

UPDATE:

tried the suggested code, but came up against the following error when running the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\nhornus154\Desktop\currencyConverter.py", line 34, in <module>
    print 'the result of the currency conversion was ', currencyAmount.quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined
```

also tried to change to decimal.Decimal, but responded that the arguments were not correct for quantize

Answer (score 0):

Precision follows [sig figs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), not fractional digits. 
you should remove the `getcontext().prec = 2`
and change the last line to:

```
print 'the result of the currency conversion was ',  currencyAmount.quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
```

**EDIT**

i've tried this code below and it works correctly:

```
#setup the decimal data type (including number of decimal places)
import decimal

#get the current value and type from the user
currencyAmount = decimal.Decimal(raw_input('please enter the amount: '))
currencyType = int(raw_input('please enter the type (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 =      yen): '))

#set the exchange rates (based on sterling)
euro = decimal.Decimal('1.5')
dollar = decimal.Decimal('2.7')
yen = decimal.Decimal('30.8')

#convert the currency into pound sterling
if (currencyType == 2):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / euro
elif (currencyType == 3):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / dollar
elif (currencyType == 4):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount / yen

#ask the user what currency they want it converted into
currencyConvert = int(raw_input('please enter the currency you would like to convert to (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 = yen): '))

#convert the currency into the new format (pound already done in previous steps)
if (currencyConvert == 2):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * euro
elif (currencyConvert == 3):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * dollar
elif (currencyConvert == 4):
    currencyAmount = currencyAmount * yen

#display the result to the user
print 'the result of the currency conversion was ',  currencyAmount.quantize(decimal.Decimal('0.00'))
```

output:

```
please enter the amount: 100
please enter the type (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 =      yen): 2
please enter the currency you would like to convert to (1 = pound, 2 = euro, 3 = dollar, 4 = yen): 4
the result of the currency conversion was  2053.33
```

Comment: thanks for help, but new error reported - have updated original code with error message